# How do I make a video responsively take as much space as it's cover image?

Tags: html, css, video

Here we have an image on top of a video, when they click the image, the video is set to `display:block;` and the image is set to `display:none;`which basically just switches the image for the video when clicked.

The image and the video are both set to `width:100%;` but even though they are the same width, the image is taller then the video. Lets say the image is 416px and the video has a height of 300px. How would I responsively make up for the missing video height so the rest of the relative elements on the page don't shift as it switches from image to video?

Here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <div onclick="coverImage()">
        <img src="http://example.com/image" alt="overview-vid-1" id="wp-image-245" width="619" height="416" style="cursor:pointer;" class="alignnone size-full wp-image-245" />
    </div>
    <div id="thevideo" style="display:none">
        [youtube-shortcode-plugin vid=""/]
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Javascript that enables the switch (just in case):

```
<script stype="text/javascript">
    function coverImage(){
        theImg=document.getElementById('wp-image-245');theImg.style.display='none';
        thevid=document.getElementById('thevideo'); thevid.style.display='block';
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/9zc9aogL/3/

Your image size is an unusual ratio - youtube videos are usually 16:8 or whatever.. the image size you picked is a little more like 16:10.

Here's the CSS that makes your video responsive and the same size as your 16:10 image. Normally, to make a youtube video responsive without black bars on the top/bottom, I'd set `padding-bottom:56.25%;` but for this image size it's `padding-bottom:62.25%`

```
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 62.25%;
    padding-top: 25px;
    height: 0;
}

.wrap iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;    
}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you do it _with_ the black bars on top and bottom?

Comment: That's a really good question.. I don't think I have an elegant answer for that.. Since the image is 16:10, you have two options. Force the image into 16:9 (squish it) or cut off the top and bottom by overlaying two absolute positioned black bars. I'd choose the latter, but you'd have to compensate for youtube's controls when choosing the size of the bars, which could be difficult.